# Outlook Corrupts PDF When SaveAsFile Used

Tags: vba, pdf, outlook

I'm using the following code to automatically export PDF files in Outlook when they arrive in my inbox.  However the file that it saves is corrupted.  The SaveAsFile method only takes one argument - the file path to save to - it doesn't say in the documentation that I can pass a filetype.  How do I save these PDF attachments without corrupting the files?

```
    Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

    Private Sub Application_Startup()

        'Declaring Variables [BD]
        Dim oOutlook As Outlook.Application
        Dim oNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
        Dim oFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

        'Intializing Variables [BD]
        Set oOutlook = Outlook.Application
        Set oNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

        Set oFolder = oNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent
        Set oFolder = oFolder.Folders("Produce Availability").Folders("Earls Organic")
        Set Items = oFolder.Items

    End Sub

    Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

    'Declaring Variables [BD]
    Dim sOutputFileName As String

    Dim oMessage As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachments

    'Initializing Variables [BD]
    sDateTime = Format(Now(), "yyyymmddhhnnss")
    sOutputFolderPath = "C:\Earls Organic\"

        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

        If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then

            Set oMessage = Item
            Set oAttachment = oMessage.Attachments

            sOutputFileName = oMessage.Subject & " " & sDateTime
            sOutputFolderPathAndName = sOutputFolderPath & sOutputFileName & ".pdf"
            oAttachment.Item(1).SaveAsFile sOutputFolderPathAndName

            Set oAttachment = Nothing
            Set oItem = Nothing

        End If

    ProgramExit:
        Exit Sub

    ErrorHandler:
            MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
            Resume ProgramExit

    End Sub
```

Comment: I think  if you are saving an attachment there is no need to define the extension right?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.saveasfile
 You only need to define the location at which to save the attachment.

Comment: Could be, I'll try that though I'm not entirely sure something like that would corrupt the file.

Comment: If you change the original extension then it's bound to corrupt it

Comment: I tried it, it saved the file without extension and it was still corrupted.

Comment: Are you sure Attachment(1) is the PDF file? Signatures and images can be recorded as attachments.  You should scan down the attachment collection checking the extension until you find the PDF file.

Comment: Good question, Tony, I'll attempt that.

Comment: Hi Tony, that was it!  Thank you!  It must have been taking the signature as an attachment.  If you'd like to post your comment as an answer I will accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, here is my comment as an answer:

Are you sure Attachment(1) is the PDF file? Signatures and images can be recorded as attachments. You should scan down the attachment collection checking the extension until you find the PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

`SaveAsFile` does not corrupt files. You never check that the file is actually a PDF - you can have other attachments which may or may not be seen as such in Outlook (such as images). You assume that the very first attachment is a PDF. Loop through all attachments do check the `Attachment.FileName` property to make sure you get what you expect.